# Bitcoin gone with "this transaction is not yet confirmed"

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit, lost-bitcoins

I sent my bitcoins from my multibit wallet, first I did a a test spend which came across and then I sent all my coins. The transaction got a triangle icon and the text "this transaction is not yet confirmed" on it. I waited 30 minutes, nothing happened. I have the default fee set so it should be okay.
So I read on the multibit page here: https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_sentBitcoinFromMultibitButTheyAreStuck.html
and at the bottom it says that I can go to tools and reset blockchain. I did and it syncronized again for a while.
But when it was completed the transaction with the triangle is gone in my transaction list but my bitcoin are not in my wallet either.
How do I revert/reset and get my bitcoins back?

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else in the help works, you can move your wallet to blockchain.info:

https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_movingAWallet.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the transaction hash ?

If yes, please check it on other websites(blockchain.info, ...) to see if the transaction is in the blockchain or not.

If no, try to create another transaction to spend the output which you spent in the last transaction, and broadcast it right away. Then, if the new transaction is put in the blockchain, you can be sure that you get your bitcoin back.